# What are the implications of Nvidia's "the way it's meant to be played"?

Tags: amd-radeon

I have an AMD Radeon 5850 (about to be 2), and today I read that Rift is a member of Nvidia's "the way it's meant to be played" program. It was suggested that as such the developers would not be speaking with or working directly with AMD for optimization, and that it would be unlikely that Crossfire support would be added until the game's release.

Are any of these implications likely? Or does it just mean that Nvidia is working closely with the developers for optimization and marketing support?

Comment: To me this question look on-topic. I think that it's directly related to software and hardware. There are problems which can come form having one manufacturer support product development. For example, Intel's C++ compilers produce (or at least used to) code which doesn't run good on AMD processors, and there's been [evidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_C%2B%2B_Compiler#Criticism)(read the referenced articles there) that it may be deliberate. If something is happening with nVidia/ATI and their programs, it would be good to know and would impact later buying decisions.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - How are we supposed to know what Nvidia is thinking? If it isn't OT the it is definitely just speculation. Is there a question that can be answered I ask?

Comment: @Nifle Research on the Internet. There is definitely some information available on those programs and it would be a good answer for this question.

Comment: This is a business related question - Off topic @and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have always taken that marketing slogan to be basically some extra advertising for nVidia at the beginning of games and some implied performance benefit on nVidia hardware that is difficult, if not impossible, to actually quantify or prove.

Effectively it is likely to be little more than a rubber stamp saying that someone at nVidia saw it working on one of the machines that they happen to have lying around which had one of their own graphics cards in.